# Persistent underline style from hell

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, coursera-api

i am a beginner and am following a tutorial on building a restaurant website. i ran into many issues most of which i have been able to solve. however, my h1 element has an underline that will not go away.

these are the styles i applied.

```
.navbar-brand h1 { /* Restaurant name */
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
  color: #6c0000;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #110000;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-brand a:hover, .navbar-brand a:focus, .navbar-brand a:visited {
  text-decoration: none; !important
}
```

i have consulted chatgpt for over 2 hours, provided my entire code, tried a different browser, cleared cache, disabled all extensions, etc. my css specifies no text decoration in relation to the h1 tag (im using the same css as my instructor for the course im doing).

i used the inspect element to troubleshoot, searching for "underline" as a keyword. the only style i found was already overriden, and toggling it on and off did nothing. pls help lol

Comment: Is it a text underline or a bottom border you're seeing? Try to set `border: none`.

Comment: Could you provide the complete html file, I can not tell anything from the code snippet

Comment: Also, `text-decoration: none; !important` should be `text-decoration: none !important;`

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] when asking a question like this.

Comment: If  you use your browser devtools inspect facility you can see exactly what and from where CSS is being applied to the a element. You should notice that it is picking-up browser's default settings which include an underline.

Answer (score 0):

You've set styles for the `visited`, `hover` and `focus` states, but not for the `a` element itself! So just add `a,` to the start of your link styles.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: 'IBM Plex Mono', monospace;
  color: #6c0000;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #110000;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a, a:visited, a:hover, a:focus {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<h1><a href="#">Text</a></h1>
```